# Need to pass parameter and event information into JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Listed below is my JavaScript function. The function works fine on IE but does not run on Firefox due to the inclusion of the `window.event` part. The way to do this so it works in other browsers other than IE is to use the parameter `e` (or something else undefined) in the parameters list in the function  header. How do I add the event to the parameters if there is already another parameter? Listed as well below is a sample call from the application to the function.

```
function entityclick(where) {
    try {
        var tempstring = new String(window.event.srcElement.id)
    }
    catch (oExp) {
        var tempstring = new String("noclickyclicky")
    }
    tempstring = tempstring.substr(0, 3)
    if (tempstring != "img") {
        if (selectedentity != "") {
            try {
                document.getElementById('tbl' + selectedentity).style.backgroundColor = ""
            }
            catch (oExc) {
            }
        }
        selectedentity = where.EntityID + where.EntityCat;
        var EntityID = where.EntityID
        var EntityCat = where.EntityCat
        var ParentEntityID = where.ParentEntityID
        var ParentEntityCat = where.ParentEntityCat
        var projtype = 0
        document.getElementById('tbl' + selectedentity).style.backgroundColor = "lightsteelblue"
        //document.all('tbl'+selectedentity).className = "HighlightMe"
        ifram = document.getElementById('detailframe')
        if (0 == 0) {
            if (EntityCat == 35)
                ifram.src = "../teams/Viewteam.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat + "&taskgrptype=" + GLOBALTASKGRPTYPE;
            else if (EntityCat == 26)
                ifram.src = "../teams/Viewteam.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat + "&taskgrptype=" + GLOBALTASKGRPTYPE;
            else if (EntityCat == 34)
                ifram.src = "../teams/Viewteam.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat + "&taskgrptype=" + GLOBALTASKGRPTYPE;
            else if (EntityCat == 10)
                ifram.src = "../solutions/ViewSolution.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat + "&taskgrptype=" + GLOBALTASKGRPTYPE;
            else if (EntityCat == 11)
                ifram.src = "../observations/ViewObservation.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat;
            else if (EntityCat == 12)
                ifram.src = "../actions/ViewAction.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat;
            else if (EntityCat == 13)
                ifram.src = "../tasks/ViewTask.aspx?taskgrpid=" + EntityID + "&taskgrpcategory=" + EntityCat + "&ptaskgrpid=" + ParentEntityID + "&ptaskgrpcategory=" + ParentEntityCat;
            ifram.style.left = '27%'
            ifram.style.display = 'block'
            //detail.style.display = 'none'
            ifram.style.zIndex = 5
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call to the function:

```
entityclick(document.getElementById('tbl' + glbRefreshID + glbRefreshCAT))
```

edit: `entityclick` is also called in certain places other ways, like:

```
entityclick(this)
```

or:

```
entityclick(document.getElementById('tbl' + GlobalExplodeID + GlobalExplodeCat))
```

Comment: what is "where"? The dom element you called the function with in your examples shouldn't have properties like "EntityID" etc.

Comment: where just seems like the name given to whatever was passed into the function (this, or the other strings which would be created by the document.getElementById examples above).

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra function as the event handler. For example

```
function handler(e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;
    entityclick(e.target, e); // have more than one parameter in your fn
}
var elem = document.getElementById("xyz");
if (elem.addEventHandler)
    elem.addEventHanlder("click", handler, false);
else
    elem.attachEvent("onclick", handler);

function entityclick(elem, e) {
/* get: a DOM node with special properties[, an Event object] */
     if (e)
          // we handle something
     else
          // we have to use defaults
}
```

Comment: nevermind previous (now deleted comment) - i now see what this is doing, will try this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: edited first post to show 2 other ways that entityclick is called - still having issue trying to get this to work, any further assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also, when passing (this) into entity click, shouldn't I be able to access the event? I currently am unable to do so.

Comment: No, this (in an event handler) refers to the dom elmement, not the event.

Comment: When using the handler function above and running tracepoints, I am not able to get anything for e or e.target - both are undefined. I am calling the handler function by setting the onclick to handler() or handler(); - either way i still get that e and e.target are undefined.  - I am also getting an exception when running in firefox saying that e and e.target are undefined. any suggestions?

Comment: another issue I am running into now is that I need to retrieve the EntityID, EntityCat, ParentEntityID and ParentEntityCat - which I am currently not having success with trying to use e

Comment: I've extended my answer to show you how you could alter the parameter interface of your function.

Answer (score 0):

was able to solving using hints from this post

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?330837-window-event-is-not-working-in-Firefox

can pass event and this to same function, which then allowed me to still get every item I needed. Thank you everyone who viewed/helped.